# wrapping text in a latex table without block

Tags: latex, word-wrap

I have a table on a page in a LaTeX document like this on it:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X | p{4.6cm} | p{3cm}}
    & & \\
    & drop variable \syntaxConcept{}; & some very long content in order to produce a high box \\
    & & \\
\end{tabularx}
```

The cell in the middle produces the following output:
[image: wrong output]

Now I tried two things:

- Getting the content in all cells to a vertical align top and
- Getting the text **not** wrapped like a block text

So the result should be like this:
[image: correct output]

But I am not able to get this kind of result. The `p{width}` always produces a wrapping block text and a normal `l` has no width parameter.

Comment: What is this construct supposed to do when the cell's content is too wide?

Comment: creating a second line that is left aligned. No block text. So like in the example from above: The line `drop variable (nt|ct|rt).<concept>;` is too long and the `variable` should **not** be on the right end of the cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `\raggedright`. And have a look at the answer to [this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12703/how-to-create-fixed-width-table-columns-with-text-raggedright-centered-raggedlef) on tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: ok, now I can left align the content. Unfortunately some rotated text columns are nore freaking out, but it is getting closer. Not I need to vertical align the text to top. Is there also a trick that I missed? Because `[t]` is not working. Just the error `Missing number, treated as zero` comes up.

Comment: @christopher2007 Put the text in a `\parbox` with the correct alignment.